# Setting correct ID from 3 corresponding columns values

Tags: sql-server-2008

**INFORMATION**

I have a table: tblTest

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
--------+---------+---------+---------
  500   |   80    |    1    |    ?
  300   |   11    |    2    |    ?
  200   |   11    |    3    |    ?
  100   |   80    |    4    |    ?
  100   |   11    |    5    |    ?
```

if the number in column2 is 80 then the corresponding column1 amount is the total.

if the number in column2 is 11 then the corresponding column1 amount equal the total.

If there are more than one 11 in column2 that's between the 80's then those corresponding column1's numbers must equal the total of the column2's 80 total above it.

Column3 is basically the ID.

Column4's value will equal the ID if Column2's value is 80

The corresponding columns 11 that equal the total of the columns 80 above must have the same ID in Column4.

In short the output should be as follows:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
--------+---------+---------+---------
  500   |   80    |    1    |    1
  300   |   11    |    2    |    1
  200   |   11    |    3    |    1
  100   |   80    |    4    |    4
  100   |   11    |    5    |    4
```

**QUESTION**

How do you use SQL to get the right ID in column4?

Comment: You've said what has to happen when everything matches up, as per your example. What's meant to happen if e.g. the `11` rows that follow a particular `80` row *don't* add up to the total in that `80` row? Also, your description "special cases" the situation of a single `11` row that follows an `80` row, but do you really need to call out that special case? If you total all of the (one) `11` row in that case, it's still meant to match the `80` total, correct?

Comment: The ones that don't add will be processed later. It is safe to assume they will add up for now.

Comment: To answer your question about the single 11's, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
First I completely left out the amount column as that can be done later.

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tbl_BatchUpdate
DECLARE @col1 int
DECLARE @col2 int
DECLARE @col3 int
DECLARE @inputVar int

OPEN cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @col1, @col2, @col3

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF (@col1 = 80) 
BEGIN
    SET @col3 = @col2
    SET @inputVar = @col2
    UPDATE tbl_BatchUpdate SET col3 = @inputVar WHERE col2 = @col2
END
ELSE IF (@col1 = 11)
BEGIN
    UPDATE tbl_BatchUpdate SET col3 = @inputVar WHERE col2 = @col2
END

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @col1, @col2, @col3
END

CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
GO
```

The way I coded it is a little weird but it gets the job done perfectly. Adding the amounts together is easy with a few SUMs and COUNTs.